# Camera doesn't be released sometimes after application re-installed

Tags: android, camera

I'm developing a camera application. Sometimes I tried to re-install the app when it is in foreground. In the installation process, the application will be killed, and the the `onPause()` won't be invoked, in which I stop the preview and release the camera resource. Under normal circumstances, the system will automatically close and release the camera, and I got the following log.

```java
03-14 15:48:36.316: E/CameraHardwareSec(83): Could not dequeue gralloc buffer!
03-14 15:48:36.316: I/CameraHardwareSec(83): int android::CameraHardwareSec::previewThreadWrapper(): calling mSecCamera->stopPreview() and waiting
03-14 15:48:36.363: I/CameraHardwareSec(83): int android::CameraHardwareSec::previewThreadWrapper(): return from wait
03-14 15:48:36.363: I/CameraHardwareSec(83): int android::CameraHardwareSec::previewThreadWrapper(): exiting
03-14 15:48:36.363: W/SecCamera(83): int android::SecCamera::stopPreview(): doing nothing because m_flag_camera_start is zero
03-14 15:48:36.363: W/SecCamera(83): int android::SecCamera::stopRecord(): doing nothing because m_flag_record_start is zero
03-14 15:48:36.363: I/SecCamera(83): DeinitCamera: m_cam_fd(29)
03-14 15:48:36.371: I/SecCamera(83): DeinitCamera: m_cam_fd2(30)
03-14 15:48:36.386: E/CameraHardwareSec(83): preview window is NULL!
03-14 15:48:36.386: I/CameraService(83): Destroying camera 0
03-14 15:48:36.386: I/CameraHardwareSec(83): int android::HAL_camera_device_close(hw_device_t*)
03-14 15:48:36.386: I/SecCamera(83): DeinitCamera : already deinitialized
03-14 15:48:36.390: W/AudioFlinger(83): session id 89 not found for pid 83
03-14 15:48:36.394: W/AudioFlinger(83): session id 90 not found for pid 83
```

However sometimes these log information didn't print out. And I guess it means the camera was not released. So when the app restarted, it throws a runtime exception "`failed to connect to camera service`" when trying open the camera.

Does anyone have any idea about why the system didn't release the camera when killed it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add permissions to your Manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: I have added the first line, but the second and third line weren't added. As far as I know, the <uses-feature> element is used as a filter by markets like Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try putting your **cam.release()** in an onDestroy instead of an onPause method? I don't know if it will help but that's. what I would to to see if it fixes it.

Comment: It seems neither onPause nor onDestroy will be invoked when the system killed the process. But thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dont allow users to use the cam when the phone is running out of memory. You don't want your app to get blamed when android kills processes.